# Expanding Button Widget to fill the entire frame in Tkinter

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I have 4 buttons in my Left Frame I would like them to resize whenever I resize

my window but it doesn't work buttons are not expanding as i expand my window

Below is my code for it

```
from tkinter import * 
root = Tk()
leftFrame = Frame(root)
leftFrame.pack(side=LEFT)
rightFrame = Frame(root)
rightFrame.pack(side=RIGHT)

button1 = Button(leftFrame,text="Round 1",fg="white",bg="black")
button2 = Button(leftFrame,text="Round 2",fg="yellow",bg="blue")
button3 = Button(leftFrame,text="Round 3",fg="purple",bg="cyan")
button4 = Button(leftFrame,text="Round 4",fg="green",bg="orange")

button1.pack(expand=True,fill='both')
button2.pack(expand=True,fill='both')
button3.pack(expand=True,fill='both')
button4.pack(expand=True,fill='both')

root.mainloop()
```

Help is appreciated

I am using Python 3.5 and Editor is Pycharm

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Actually, your buttons **are** filling the entire frame. The problem is that the frames aren't filling the root window. This is because you `pack` the frames without specifying that they should grow to fill their parent.

`pack` your frames like this:

```
leftFrame = Frame(root)
leftFrame.pack(side=LEFT, expand=True, fill='both')
rightFrame = Frame(root)
rightFrame.pack(side=RIGHT, expand=True, fill='both')
```

Comment: Thanks mate Problem Solved